# Printing commands to bat/cmd file with Java

Tags: java, batch-file

How to print commands to bat/cmd file using Java? I have created a method that opens this `bat` file and now the program should write commands to this `bat` file. For instance, I have a string variable "Command" and the program must write this command to `bat` file.

Here I attach the code.

```
private static void openBat(){
    File file = new File(lockerPath);
    try {
        if (file.exists()) {
            Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + lockerPath);
            pro.waitFor();
        } else {
            System.out.println("file does not exist");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

This is the code to open `bat` file, and the next code is to write commands:

```
private static void printing(int password ){
    try {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C", lockerPath);
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        process.waitFor();
        List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
        commands.add(String.valueOf(password));
        processBuilder.command(commands);
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It doesn't write anything to the file.
I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you run your `.bat` file from a [command prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe), then, after it starts running, does it prompt the user to enter a password and wait for the user to enter something? If that is the case, then do you want your Java program to simulate the user entering his password?

Comment: @Abra I run .bat file by method openBat, then it is waiting while the user enter a password. So method printing should write to the opened .bat file command (in my case password). So, yes, I want that Java will enter password instead of user

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks to me like you want to launch some application and that application prompts the user to enter a password, for example when you open a password-protected PDF file with [Adobe Acrobat Reader](https://get.adobe.com/reader/). It also looks like you want to first launch the application and then execute a separate [Windows] batch file that simply sends the password to the launched application. I don't think this is possible. What application are you trying to launch?

Comment: @Abra, I’ve created a bat file, and when I open this file it is waiting for the password, that user has to insert. The program I am trying to make should work in the following way:
1) open this bat file, that is already created
2) when this bat file is waiting for the user password, my program has to write it instead of student.
So it looks like my program opens bat file and at once insert the password here. Just imagine that the user has to write password there, but my program does it instead of user.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't think I completely understand your question. If you just want to simulate the user entering a value to a batch file via a java program, then the below code does that.

First I wrote a batch file.

```
@echo off
set /P pw=
echo You entered: %pw%
```

It simply waits for the user to enter a value and assigns that value to a variable named `pw`. After the user enters the value, the batch file displays the entered value.

Here is the java code that runs the above batch file and enters a value.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "getusrpw.bat");
        try {
            Process p = pb.start(); // throws java.io.IOException
            BufferedReader stdout = p.inputReader();
            BufferedReader stderr = p.errorReader();
            BufferedWriter stdin = p.outputWriter();
            stdin.write("secret");
            stdin.newLine();
            stdin.flush();
            String output = stdout.readLine();
            while (output != null) {
                System.out.println("OUT> " + output);
                output = stdout.readLine();
            }
            String error = stderr.readLine();
            while (error != null) {
                System.out.println("ERR> " + error);
                error = stderr.readLine();
            }
            int exitStatus = p.waitFor(); // throws java.lang.InterruptedException
            System.out.println("Process exit status = " + exitStatus);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException | IOException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

- The name of the batch file is `getusrpw.bat`.
- `stdout` is for reading output generated by the batch file.
- `stderr` is for reading error output. Note that there may be no error output.
- `stdin` is for sending input to the batch file.
- Note that methods `inputReader`, `outputWriter` and `errorReader` were added in JDK 17. If you are using an earlier version, use methods `getInputStream`, `getOutputStream` and `getErrorStream`, respectively.
- The Java program enters the value *secret*.
- The Java program prints the output generated by the batch file.

When I run the above Java code, it produces the following output:

```
OUT> You entered: secret
Process exit status = 0
```